# Calling a function in angular 1.5 as a new component opens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I have a component where on click of a button i am calling another component.

```
model.alert = function () {
            modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                template: '<abc-xyz return-value="model" on-cancel="Cancel()"></abc-xyz>',
                scope: modalScope,
                backdrop: 'static',
                windowClass: 'callrecord-popup'
            });

            modalScope.Cancel = function () {
                modalInstance.close();
            }            
        }
```

Now I want to call a function int that abc-xyz component as soon as it opens.

the js of the component is:

```
   function taxReconciliationAlertController($scope) {
            var model = this;
// Inside here i have written the function
function xyz(){
//some code here which returns data to html
}    
}
```

As soon as I click the button in the first component it should call this xyz function, but I am unable to call it. Could somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke the function using xyz(); in the abc-xyz component's controller below the definition of xyz() function.